# Reading a CSV file from Git LFS using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, git, streamlit, git-lfs

I am currently trying to create a dataframe using pd.read_csv, but the file I am trying to read from is stored in Git LFS since it is around 600 MB. The output I'm getting is referencing the pointer file and not the file itself that contains the data.

I've tried using the raw link for the file:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(page_title='Distance Tool')
st.header('Counties Within Mile Radius')
st.subheader('Choose a city:')
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pedroj92224/krekk/Distances_Offline.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, on_bad_lines='skip')
dfa = df.loc[ :, df.columns != 'County']

columnz = st.selectbox("Choose a city", dfa.columns)
```

But instead of a dropdown box with the columns of my file (which works locally on Streamlit) I end up getting the following output in my box:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
```

How do I access the contents of the actual .csv file from Git LFS?

Here is the repository: https://github.com/pedroj92224/krekk

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-lfs%5D+%5Bgithub%5D+access+file

Comment: The actual URL is https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/pedroj92224/krekk/master/Distances_Offline.csv